# MPMoviePlayerViewController Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints

Tags: objective-c, ios11, iphone-x, xcode9.1

I have an ios app and it crashes on iPhone X works fine on other iPhones. I use `objective c` with `XIB`. I have gone through existing posts for constraints issue. That hasn't helped. The `Xcode` version is 9.1 The error reported on the `Xcode` debug console is below.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks & Regards,
Rakesh

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x60000028bd60 h=-&- v=-&- _UIBackdropContentView:0x7fb5c34588c0.midY == _UIBackdropView:0x7fb5c3404fa0.midY   (active)>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x60000028bc20 h=-&- v=-&- _UIBackdropContentView:0x7fb5c34588c0.height == _UIBackdropView:0x7fb5c3404fa0.height   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000484510 V:|-(0)-[UIStatusBar_Modern:0x7fb5c34058f0]   (active, names: '|':_UIBackdropContentView:0x7fb5c34588c0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000484600 UIStatusBar_Modern:0x7fb5c34058f0.height == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000004845b0 V:[UIStatusBar_Modern:0x7fb5c34058f0]-(0)-[UIView:0x7fb5c3431870]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000028eba0 UIView:0x7fb5c3431870.top == _UIBackdropView:0x7fb5c3404fa0.top + 44   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000004845b0 V:[UIStatusBar_Modern:0x7fb5c34058f0]-(0)-[UIView:0x7fb5c3431870]   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

The piece of code where this problem occurs is below.

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 3.2) {
    NSString *baseUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"file://%@//%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],[self.video valueForKey:@"VideoFile"]];
    baseUrl = [baseUrl stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"//"];
    baseUrl = [baseUrl stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
    NewVideoController *videoController = [[[NewVideoController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:baseUrl]] autorelease];

    [videoController.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];

    //[videoController.view prepareToPlay];
    //[videoController.view setFrame: self.bounds];  // player's frame must match parent's
    videoController.view.frame = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]keyWindow].bounds;
    //[videoController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,150, 320, 200)];
    // ...
    //[videoController play];
    //self.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=YES;
    videoController.moviePlayer.useApplicationAudioSession = NO;
    //videoController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:videoController];     
}
```

[image: Screen shot for UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints breakpoint]
[image: Screen shot for UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints breakpoint]
[image: Screen shot for UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints breakpoint]
[image: Screenshot at breakpoint UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints IPhone simulator screen is there. The status bar is overlapped by some element "done" and something]

After continuing from this breakpoint the video screen is displayed on tech simulator. On the real iPhoneX it crashes.

Comment: Did you able to find the solution?